# Is this question a bad question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I asked [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1546944/adding-python-and-c-file-to-new-item) recently on Super User and even included my work to solve the problem. I am wondering: is it a bad question, is it missing anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you think it's a bad question? It doesn't have any downvotes (at the time of writing), it just doesn't have an answer yet. Not everyone visits Super User on a daily basis, and it's just over 24 hours old. Super User sees [more than 100 new questions per day, on average](https://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/1120804/questions-per-day-n-day-moving-average?fromDate=2018-01-01&numberOfDays=30#graph), the resident Windows registry experts might have been busy answering other questions.

Showing your work is good, please keep investigating and if you're finally stuck, you can use some of your reputation to post a [bounty](https://superuser.com/help/bounty) which will draw more attention to the question.

Comment: Yeah I was just thinking that the flux of users going into the site. thanks